# appending key-value in pandas from columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data. I need to form a dictionary from this. There are 20 columns with y1_bin, y2_bin, .....y20_bin. In this toy data, I have shown three columns only.

```
    Firm  y1    y2    y3   prob_y1   prob_y2   prob_y3 y1_bin y2_bin y3_bin
0     A   1     2     7  0.006897  0.000421  0.002729   binA   binA   binB
1     B   2     3    45  0.013793  0.000632  0.017544   binA   binA   binE
2     C   3     4    40  0.020690  0.000842  0.015595   binA   binA   binE
3     D   4     7     3  0.027586  0.001474  0.001170   binA   binB   binA
4     E   5     9     4  0.034483  0.001895  0.001559   binB   binB   binA
5     F   6   400    12  0.041379  0.084211  0.004678   binB   binH   binC
6     G   7    50    32  0.048276  0.010526  0.012476   binB   binF   binE
7     H   8    70     0  0.055172  0.014737  0.000000   binB   binF   binA
8     I   9    95    76  0.062069  0.020000  0.029630   binB   binF   binF
9     J  10    98     1  0.068966  0.020632  0.000390   binC   binF   binA
10    K  20     2    45  0.137931  0.000421  0.017544   binD   binA   binE
11    L  30    10  2000  0.206897  0.002105  0.779727   binE   binC   binH
12    M  40  4000   300  0.275862  0.842105  0.116959   binE   binH   binH
```

I have written following syntax to append the keys and values:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(list)
for k, v, m,j in zip(df33.Firm.values, df33.y2_bin.values, df33.y1_bin.values, df33.y3_bin.values):
    mydict[k].append(v)
    mydict[k].append(m)
    mydict[k].append(j)

print(mydict)
```

This is expected result (which I can get from above for loop- and i know this is not the most efficient way to write code.). Is there a better way to make this efficient so that I do not have to keep adding `df33.***.values`  and  `mydict[k].append(****)` in the for loop.

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': ['binA', 'binA', 'binB'], 'C': ['binA', 'binA', 'binE'], 'B': ['binA', 'binA', 'binE'], 'E': ['binB', 'binB', 'binA'], 'D': ['binB', 'binA', 'binA'], 'G': ['binF', 'binB', 'binE'], 'F': ['binH', 'binB', 'binC'], 'I': ['binF', 'binB', 'binF'], 'H': ['binF', 'binB', 'binA'], 'K': ['binA', 'binD', 'binE'], 'J': ['binF', 'binC', 'binA'], 'M': ['binH', 'binE', 'binH'], 'L': ['binC', 'binE', 'binH']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([
      {'Firm': 'A', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
      {'Firm': 'A', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
      {'Firm': 'B', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
      {'Firm': 'B', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
      ...
  ])

my_dict = dict(zip(df.Firm, [list(df.get(f'y{idx}_bin').values) for idx in range(1, 31)]))

#Output
{'A': ['binA', 'binA', 'binA', 'binA'],
 'B': ['binB', 'binB', 'binB', 'binB']
  ...
}
```

Comment: Nope, that does not help because I want to avoid typing the column names again and again in my_dict.

Comment: What about the updated version, using list comprehensions?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `DataFrame.to_dict` method with a list comprehension as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
      {'Firm': 'A', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
      {'Firm': 'A', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
      {'Firm': 'B', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
      {'Firm': 'B', 'y1_bin': 'binA', 'y2_bin': 'binA', 'y3_bin': 'binB'},
  ])

# set column 'Firm' as the index (needed for df.to_dict() to work)
df.set_index('Firm', inplace=True)

my_dict = {k: list(v.values()) for k, v in df.to_dict('index').items()}

# output:
{'A': ['binA', 'binA', 'binB'], 'B': ['binA', 'binA', 'binB']}
```

Take a look at [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) for more info on its output